# How do I check if I have Cyanogenmod on my phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, linux, shell

Is it possible to check using shell whether or not Cyanogenmod is installed on a device?

In other words, something like `uname -a` (which tells the system Linux version and architecture).

Can the version be determined as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to do `uname -a` on my CM10.1 (Samsung Galaxy S2) on the built-in Terminal app.

It returns:

> Linux localhost 3.0.31-CM-g17c7b6e #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 19 01:11:17
>   PST 2013 armv71 GNU/Linux

Kernel version: `3.0.31-CM-g17c7b6e`
SMP: `Symmetric Multi-Processor support`
PREEMPT: `kernel preemption is enabled`
Kernel date: `Tue Feb 19 01:11:17 PST 2013`
Processor: `armv71`

Comment: Can you explain the rest of the output? What is g17c7b6e, PREEMPT?

Comment: @KshitizSharma See my updates.

Comment: Umm, what if Android system is stock but kernel is of CM? Although it is not something we see everyday, I think `uname -a` might not be perfect but it's quite good! `uname -a` also might not be best if custom kernel is used and developer decided to tweak the name.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to simply go to *Settings→About phone*, where you should see (depending on your CyanogenMod version) an item "CyanogenMod updates", and (with all CM versions) "CyanogenMod-Version":

[image: About Phone: CM Stats and Kernel version] [image: About phone: CM version] [image: About phone: CM version (German)]

Answer (score 0):

In my CM12, I can do:

```
adb shell getprop | grep -i cyanogenmod
```

and the result it shows is:

```
[ro.build.host]: [cyanogenmod]
[ro.cmlegal.url]: [https://www.cyanogenmod.org/docs/privacy]
[ro.error.receiver.system.apps]: [org.cyanogenmod.bugreport]
[ro.rommanager.developerid]: [cyanogenmod]
```

If you don't see `cyanogenmod` anywhere then either `build.prop` is deliberately tweaked to not display CM anywhere, or the device isn't running Cyanogenmod at all.

Comment: `/etc/CHANGES.txt` and `/etc/CHANGELOG-CM.txt` also can be considered.